# error method http test with jasmine (angular 7)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have a simple application in angular 7, which makes a list request of gifs, informing the amount of gifs and the search term, using giphy api.

I want to create a test that makes a request, and verify that the result of the list of gifs is greater than 0.

but I'm having many errors and I'm not understanding why

**Service**

```
private apiKey:string = "123";
private shortUrl:string = "//api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q="

searchGif(term:string, limit:number):Observable<Gif[]> {
     let url:string = this.getUrl(term, limit);
     return  this.http.get<Gif[]>(`${url}/`);
}
```

**Test**

```
let service: GifSearchService;
let httpMock: any
let limit: number = 1;
let term: string = "dogs";

beforeEach(() => {
    httpMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('http', [ 'get', 'post' ]);
    service = new GifSearchService(httpMock);
});

it('Should return value when search for gifs', () => {
    let result = service.searchGif(term, limit);
    expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
```

**Error**

> ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts(14,60): error
>   TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
>   src/app/gif-list/gif-list.component.spec.ts(33,19): error TS2339:
>   Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Comment: Why you want to test your API in frontend code? Unit test should be used to test a specific unit of code. API should be tested in backend environment IMO.

Comment: I'm using the api from giphy, I only have the frontend.

Comment: But you can check something only during build process. When you create your build, giphy can change API and your unit test doesn't have any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only test that would make sense would be to test if it is returning an Observable... like so..

```
expect(results).toEqual(jasmine.any(Observable))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have this error: expected undefined to equal <jasmine.any(Observable)>.

Comment: The test as written is only validating a funtion pointer which points to the function that returns an observable. Not too useful as ut will always work.  To test the execution of the obsv subscribe to it instead

Comment: my function return it searchGif(term:string, limit:number):Observable<Gif[]>